# How to find two columns that have same values in Solr

Tags: mysql, sql, solr

I want to find two columns in a table that have same values through Solr, no specific value targeted. Just like mysql shown below could be done:

```
select A from table t
where A.value == B.value
```

A and B are both columns in table t.
I wanna use Solr instead of access mysql, please tell me what to do or at least give me a clue.

Comment: SQL should be `select A from table t
where A.value = B.value`

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=solr+compare+two+fields

Comment: i want these two columns to be compared at the time of indexing, maybe i will try add another boolean field. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can group it easy with: 
group.field=id&group=true&group.limit=100

But you have still other values in this solution... It's not the best :D

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This may come out with lots of groups that have different values.........it may cost too much.......